# Max bit size in Craftsman fixed-base router

Tags: router, router-bit, router-table

I have a Craftsman router, model 320.17541, and a Craftsman router table, model 320.28180.

The manual for the router indicates that the max diameter for a bit should be 1 1/4", due to the size of the opening in the sub-base. The manual for the table indicates to remove the sub-base from the router to install it in the table. Is the max size bit then just limited by the size of the opening in the table?

On a somewhat related note, the lack of a sub-base means that a lot of dust falls into the motor housing.

---

Will add links later, as I'm on mobile right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other limit on the maximum size of the bit is whether you have speed control, either built in or as an external controller. Speed at which the outside edge of the bit is travelling for the same RPM is proportional to radius, and it isn't hard to get up to speeds that are unsafe unless you can reduce them.

Also, that same effect means more torque back on the router; you may need to take a much shallower cut or move to a more powerful router.